# Releasing application in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I want to release an android application to android market. Different versions of this application should run on different Android platforms, i.e. 1.5, 1.6, 2.1, and 2.2. How can I release these separate versions under one app name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it's best to have *one* package that works on *all* platforms.

When this isn't possible, or when you really want to make use of features on newer platforms and still support older ones, [Android Market now has support for multiple APK files](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html). With this feature, you can upload several APK files, each targeting different Android versions, and release them under one app name.